# The specified UUID is not allowed for this operation

Tags: ios, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, uuid

I am developing an IOS Application for our Bluetooth Low Energy device, and I am running into a problem whereas i am unable to write to a certain characteristic (that is set to require authenticated write and authenticated read) on a BGM111.

**The problem i am experiencing happens in the following order:**

> First Run:
>           1.) Connect to device
>           2.) Write a "secret" code to the device, causing it to enable bonding mode
>           3.) Read the characteristic that is set to Authenticated Read, forcing the IOS App to request to pair with it (user presses Allow
>   Pair)
>           4.) Write the desired value to the characteristic, which works on this run   Second Run and beyond (any time after closing the
>   application, and re-opening it):
>           1.) Connect to device
>           2.) Write "secret" code again, to ensure this is still a valid device, (again causing enabling of bonding mode)
>           3.) Read the characteristic again (works)
>           4.) Write the desired value to the characteristic, which this time gives the error of "The specified UUID is not allowed for this
>   operation." which has an error code value of 8

Why am I getting this issue?

Answer (score 0):

BGM111 can connect with multiple device ?

Please change device once and connnect again

i think same device will connect will give same udid it is already there so it's making issue

Comment: Not sure i understand what your first question is... We are using the IOS App to connect to 1 BGM111 device at the moment